# Python version error in Jupyter of Google DataProc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I created a DataProc cluster with Jupyter initialization. The image version I used is 1.4. I ssh to both master and worker nodes and run `python --version`, and both show `Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.`.

However, when I try to run the example from Google:
[Reading and writing data from BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example) with Jupyter (PySpark kernel), it gives the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1cf15cbebfd5> in <module>
     55 
     56 # Display 10 results.
---> 57 pprint.pprint(word_counts.take(10))
     58 
     59 

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1358 
   1359             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1360             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1361 
   1362             items += res

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
   1049         # SparkContext#runJob.
   1050         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
-> 1051         sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
   1052         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
   1053 

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 24.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 24.0 (TID 563, test-1-w-0.c.abc.internal, executor 3): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 262, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1888)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1875)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1875)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2058)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2047)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 262, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1124)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

I don't understand why the master-worker python version error can happen. In addition, when I submit this job from local command line, it works without problem. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the full command you used to create the cluster? Including any metadata flags and --initialization-actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The described issue should only appear when using the initialization actions, which were originally written for Dataproc 1.2 or older. When using Dataproc image-versions 1.3 or newer you should be using [Dataproc Optional Components](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/overview) to install Juptyer instead of the initialization-action; this approach will be more reliable and also ensures all the relevant version settings are correct through the whole cluster:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-name \
  --optional-components=JUPYTER \
  --image-version=1.4 \
  ... other flags
```

Comment: The problem with the optional component is that I won't be able to customize the Jupyter setup. For example, the Jupyter has a 'quit' botton on up-right corner. I want to disable that botton, and I can modify setup-jupyter-kernel.sh to disable it. However, with the optional component, I won't be able to do it at the creation time (Can modify configuration after creation but it's not ideal). Any suggestions for doing that at creation time?

Comment: You can write your own init action that will modify `setup-jupyter-kernel.sh` installed by the optional component during cluster start up.

Comment: Is the concern that modifying that after creation isn't ideal because it will take longer to start up? In practice, starting up with optional components is much faster than init actions already because optional components don't need to download anything from the internet, so most likely even after reconfiguring and restarting Jupyter in an init action, the overall deploy time will be faster than using an init action. If you want very deep customizations you could consider using [custom images](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images).

Comment: You can also send suggestions for configurability options you want to dataproc-feedback@google.com and it's possible some common options will become supported first-class via cluster properties

Comment: My goal is to provide a creation script, so that anybody can use it to create their own cluster if they need to. Being able to customize the jupyter.sh and setup-jupyter-kernel.sh can allow users create cluster with expected behavior easily (as opposed to modifying configuration manually everytime). But the problem is that if I use jupyter.sh to initialize it, I encountered the problem in this question. Any chance you know which part of jupyter.sh is causing the issue?